# What is the default config file name for hystrix

Tags: configuration, hystrix, netflix-archaius

There are lots of setting for hystrix listed in https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration. But I didn't find in the document what is the default properties file name that will be loaded by hystrix/archaius by default.

My question is, is there a default properties file? If not, how can I specifiy one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [Getting Started](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Getting-Started) page in Archaius wiki, you will find this explanation:

> There are two ways to get Archaius working out of the box by using a local configuration file to feed dynamic properties to your application.
>
> - By default, Archaius will look for a file named “config.properties” on the application’s classpath and read its content as configuration properties. The file can be also in a jar file’s root directory.
> - In addition, you can define a system property `archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls` that contains the URL path to a local configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Manual always worth to be read one more time.